# Css: Images moving up and down with window resizing

Tags: html, css

This is my first website, I'm making it for home automation using my **Raspberry Pi.**

I'll hyperlink the images and use them as buttons to activate the python scripts.

**Problem** is that I'm trying to create something like a panel, I've added a steel texture and centered it. I'm now trying to put an image on top of it to use as a button; however when the browser is resized my image moves up and down.

I'm trying to make a responsive design to be able to use it off the phone too.

**Code** (They're two sperate files for **HTML** and **CSS** but I just layed them out on top of one another):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Body */
body {
  font-family: source-sans-pro;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: #E0115F;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2C9AB7;
}
.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: undefined;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero_header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.controls {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.pi_logo_top{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 15px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 80%;
  min-width: 5%;
  max-width: none;
}
.controls {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca         99%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */;
}
.lights_off {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 8%;
  min-width: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: -10px;
  top: -200px;
}
#rcorners {
  border-radius: 45px;
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 5px; 
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Raspberry Pi Home Automation</title>
 <link href="css/singlePageTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
 <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container"> 
   <header> <a href="">
     <h4 class="logo">Home Automation</h4>
     <img src = "https://seeklogo.com/images/R/raspberry-pi-logo-8240ABBDFE-seeklogo.com.png" alt = "Raspberry Pi Logo" class = "pi_logo_top">
   </a>
   </header>
     <div class="controls">
         <center><img src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/dirty-metal-texture_1048-4784.jpg" id = "rcorners"  alt=""></center>
     </div>
     <div>
         <img src="images/Light_off.png" class="lights_off" alt="light off"> 
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

We're specifically looking at `.lights_off { position: relative; max-width: 8%; min-width: none; overflow: hidden; right: -10px; top: -200px; }` it moves up and down when I resize the browser.

I want to position it somewhere and want it to **stay** there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a container to wrap the image and use flex to position the image. But the image has to be inside the tag `.controls` and then you can position the wrapper by absolute:

HTML:

```
<div class='image_container'>
    <img src="//your image" class="lights_off" alt="light off"> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.controls{
position: relative;
}
.lights_off {
  max-width: 8%;
  min-width: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image_container{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Check the demo code here: https://codepen.io/tien-bui/pen/EGweXJ

Comment: Works well, thanks! Couldn't upvote because of rep :(

Answer (score 1):

When you resize the browser , the height of the div changes , so it is normal that the top:-200px would not work . 
You should place the image inside the above div , and give it an absolute position and then put percentages instead of px .

```
 <style>
 .lights_off {
  position:absolute;
  max-width: 8%;
  min-width: none;
  bottom:20%;
  z-index:99
  right: -10px;

}
 </style>
      <div class="controls">
            <center><img src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/dirty-metal-texture_1048-4784.jpg" id = "rcorners"  alt=""></center>


            <img src="images/Light_off.png" class="lights_off" alt="light off"> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks! Couldn't upvote because of rep :(